# IdTcpServer crashes

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

[image]
[image]

I am using indy's tcp server / client and everything works fine(fixed a few bugs),but there is one bug that is bugging me.

When I freeze all the threads & then kill the process of the tcp client the server crashes and keeps raising that error^ nonstop in the tcpserver.

Is there a way to handle that error in Delphi 6 and other socket errors and prevent the server from crashing(I am using delphi 6 / windows 8 64-bits(probably not needed but I never tested it on my win 7 so...)/ indy 9 / Indy TCP Server & Client)?

Comment: What "bugs" did you fix in `TIdTCPClient`/`TIdTCPServer`?

Comment: only one bug is related to this(I think),I had forgotten to call TThreadList.UnlockList and it caused the clients to still connect to the server but the server never added them to the thread list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server is not crashing.  `EIdSocketError` is a perfectly normal exception for `TIdTCPServer` to encounter when a client connection is closed/lost.  That is normal behavior.  `TIdTCPserver` will handle it internally for you and close the socket if the exception escapes into the server (which you should allow it to do - if you catch it yourself, re-raise it after you are done with it).  The only reason you see the exception at all is because the debugger reports it before your app sees it.  Simply press F9 to let the debugger pass it to the app for normal handling, or else configure the debugger to ignore Indy `EIdException`-based exceptions.

Comment: Sorry if I was misleading,I meant that when I press F9 it keeps raising the same exception over and over.

Comment: Are you still trying to write to the connection after the exception?. Better than the screenshots would be the relevant code in the question. Did you know which line of your code raises the exception, if any?

Comment: `ledata:=AThread.Connection.ReadLn('',10);`
`Client := PClient(AThread.Data); <-- exception is raised here.`

Comment: ah nvm it was probably just some bug in the dissembler or something(it only crashes once it a while anyways so I could care less).

Comment: @user0: What you describe typically happens if you are catching but not re-raising Indy exceptions, so the server does not know the connection is gone and your code ends up accessing the same dead connection over and over. Looking at your screenshot, you are actually doing that. You need to either get rid of your `try/except` block completely, or at least re-raise any `EIdException`-derived exception you catch. You also need to get rid of your checks for `AThread.Terminated` and `AThread.Connection.Connected` either way. They don't belong there. Let the exceptions tell you the socket state.

Comment: yes,that pretty much solved my problem and I was able to determine what the cause of the error was.Thank you :D @Remy Lebeau

Answer (score 0):

And please make sure you use a more recent version of Indy than that installed in D7 (you need to remove the old version first). There are crashing threading bugs < 9.0.18

Comment: I am now using pure Winsock and I plan to not ever have to use Indy again.So it's not necessary.